# From the concatenated fasta file, how to find individual range of locations in each protein sequence

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta

May be this question is too generalized, but I am completely stuck at this. Any type of help is appreciated:

I have a protein fasta file (protein.txt) like:

```
>a
mnspq
>b
rstuvw
>c
mnqa
```

Note that the length of a, b and c proteins are 5,6 and 4 respectively (total length = 15)

now I have extracted some random ranges (calculation is based on total length) and save it (file1.txt) as:

```
2-3
4-10
11-14
```

The length of each protein (within the total length) as seen in protein file is saved in another file (file2.txt) as:

```
a  1-5
b  6-11
c  12-15
```

Now from file1 values, I want to modify the file2 values and try to calculate individual range for each protein sequence, For the above input, the output will be:

```
a   2-3,4-5
b   1-5, 6
c   2-5
```

In other words, if I first concatenate my all sequences and derermine some ranges from the concatenated file, how can I find individual range of locations in each protein sequence

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `c 1-3` instead?

Comment: upps.. my fault.. you are absolutely right sir..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the last line of the answer should be `c 1-3`:

```
|---a---| |---b-----| |--c--|
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
  |-| |-----------| |-----|
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4
```

Perl to the rescue! First, the ranges from file1 are read into an array. Then, proteins are read from file2, and for each range that overlaps with the range, the "start" and "end" are computed and printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ranges;
open my $f1, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$f1>) {
    chomp;
    push @ranges, [ split /-/ ];
}

open my $f2, '<', 'file2.txt' or die $!;
while (<$f2>) {
    my ($protein, $range) = split;
    print "$protein";
    my $separator = ' ';
    my ($from, $to) = split /-/, $range;

    shift @ranges while @ranges && $ranges[0][1] < $from;
    last unless @ranges;

    while (@ranges && $ranges[0][0] <= $to) {
        my $start = $ranges[0][0];
        $start = $from if $from > $start;
        my $end = $ranges[0][1];
        $end = $to if $end > $to;
        $_ -= $from - 1 for $start, $end;

        print $separator, $start == $end ? $start : "$start-$end";
        $separator = ',';

        if ($ranges[0][1] < $to) {
            shift @ranges;
        } else {
            $ranges[0][0] = $to + 1;
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```